# Can I avoid this query in the While loop to speed up page loading?

Tags: php

My code is constructing a web page where I display multiple tables of data based on a machine ID (`machine_id`). The end user wants to be able to scroll through all tables on a single page versus having a single page for each individual machine.

Attached is a screenshot of what the page looks like (actually displays more than just two tables on the page). Can I modify my code so that I'm not making multiple queries in the While loop as the `machine_id` changes?

---

```
$db = new Database();

$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT machine_id, machine_name, display_order FROM machines WHERE active_board = 'YES' ORDER BY display_order ASC");

echo "<table>";

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))  {

    $mach_id = $row["machine_id"];
    $machine_name = $row["machine_name"];
    $presspage = $row["machine_id"];
    $machine_name = $row["machine_name"];
    $daycount = '7';

    $rows = $db -> select("SELECT a.machine_id, a.job_id, a.component, a.production_date, a.colors, a.hours, a.quantity, a.is_completed, a.artwork_image,
          j.job_id, j.job_number, j.customer_id, j.job_name, j.total_cost, j.due_date, j.rework, j.pps, j.personalization, j.shipped, j.wave_csr,
          c.customer_id, c.customer_name, c.board_color, c.text_color, u.full_name, p.component_name, d.delivery_method
          FROM job_assignments a
          LEFT JOIN jobs j ON a.job_id = j.job_id
          LEFT JOIN customers c ON j.customer_id = c.customer_id
          LEFT JOIN users u ON j.wave_csr = u.user_id
          LEFT JOIN job_components p ON a.component = p.component_code
          LEFT JOIN delivery_methods d ON j.method_id = d.method_id
          WHERE a.machine_id = $presspage
          ORDER BY j.job_number ASC");

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>";

echo "<div id='dhtmlgoodies_dragDropContainer'>";

 echo   "<div id='dhtmlgoodies_mainContainer' align='center' vertical-align='middle'>";

    echo "<h2>" . $machine_name . "</h2>";

    for($x=0;$x<$daycount;$x++) {
            $thehours = 0;
            $theday = date('l M d', strtotime($date . " + {$x} day"));
            $theday2 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date . " + {$x} day"));
            $daycode = date('Md', strtotime($date . " + {$x} day"));
            $totalhours = 0;
            $pastdue_hours = 0;
            $totalvalue = 0.00;

            echo "<div style='width:180px; height:1500px; '>";
            echo "<p>" . $theday . "</p>";

            foreach ($rows as $row) {
                $prod_date = $row["production_date"];
                $shipped = $row["shipped"];
                $hours = $row["hours"];
                $value = $row["total_cost"];
                $assignment_completed = 0;
                $is_completed = $row["is_completed"];

                if (($prod_date < date('Y-m-d')) AND ($shipped == 'NO') ) {
                    $prod_date = date('Y-m-d');
                };
                        ...
```

[Screenshot example of web page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLs6d.png)

Comment: why not join the machine table to the second SQL statement, and execute the query once? You have to adjust the loop to start a new table when the machine id changes, but that shouldn't be much of a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join both the queries as

```
SELECT m.machine_id, m.machine_name, m.display_order, a.job_id, a.component, a.production_date, a.colors, a.hours, a.quantity, a.is_completed, a.artwork_image,
  j.job_id, j.job_number, j.customer_id, j.job_name, j.total_cost, j.due_date, j.rework, j.pps, j.personalization, j.shipped, j.wave_csr,
  c.customer_id, c.customer_name, c.board_color, c.text_color, u.full_name, p.component_name, d.delivery_method
FROM 
  machines m
  LEFT JOIN job_assignments a USING (machine_id)
  LEFT JOIN jobs j ON a.job_id = j.job_id
  LEFT JOIN customers c ON j.customer_id = c.customer_id
  LEFT JOIN users u ON j.wave_csr = u.user_id
  LEFT JOIN job_components p ON a.component = p.component_code
  LEFT JOIN delivery_methods d ON j.method_id = d.method_id
WHERE a.machine_id = $presspage and m.active_board = 'YES'
ORDER BY m.display_order, j.job_number;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first get all the machine ids from the first query into an array, then execute the second query for all machine ids in that array all at once. Below is a demonstrated example:

```
$db = new Database();


$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT machine_id, machine_name, display_order FROM machines WHERE active_board = 'YES' ORDER BY display_order ASC");

$active_board_machine_ids = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))  {
  $active_board_machine_ids[] = $row["machine_id"];
}

$rows = $db -> select("SELECT a.machine_id, a.job_id, a.component, a.production_date, a.colors, a.hours, a.quantity, a.is_completed, a.artwork_image,
      j.job_id, j.job_number, j.customer_id, j.job_name, j.total_cost, j.due_date, j.rework, j.pps, j.personalization, j.shipped, j.wave_csr,
      c.customer_id, c.customer_name, c.board_color, c.text_color, u.full_name, p.component_name, d.delivery_method
      FROM job_assignments a
      LEFT JOIN jobs j ON a.job_id = j.job_id
      LEFT JOIN customers c ON j.customer_id = c.customer_id
      LEFT JOIN users u ON j.wave_csr = u.user_id
      LEFT JOIN job_components p ON a.component = p.component_code
      LEFT JOIN delivery_methods d ON j.method_id = d.method_id
      WHERE a.machine_id IN ('".implode("','",$active_board_machine_ids)."')
      ORDER BY j.job_number ASC");
```